# Maximum YouTube video stream audio bitrate

Tags: encoding, codec

I know that YouTube no allows 96kHz audio. But I also worry about second thing the bitrate. How much is possible maximum to get from YouTube stream? I'v only found recommended value of 384kbps, but I need to know if this number will be reduced by YouTube if I use bigger and if using bigger number is possible at all.

Also what are other services that allows this or higher quality of audio being streamed along with video.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube support indicates that they stream at 128 kbps AAC for normal users, and 256 kbps AAC for premium ones.

Source 1: https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/168815?hl=en

Source 2: https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/338369?msgid=348540